# How to make canonical questions acceptably specific

Tags: discussion, canonical

We want to have canonical questions, with good canonical answers, for frequently asked questions. For a canonical question to be useful if must not be cluttered with details that can vary from case to case. But we do not allow questions to be vague or to lack details.  So we seem to have an essential tension here. How do we ensure that canonical questions are not closed?

Comment: See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Rather than asking "What are the possible causes of X?", ask something more the form "How can I debug X?"