# Question closed because unclear. Edits accepted, not reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

The question *[Inexplicit 'task' in Chrome Performance DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329780/inexplicit-task-in-chrome-perfomance-devtools)* was asked by someone, **not me**. I found it by googling, because I had the exact same problem.

The question was put "on hold" because "**unclear what you're asking**".
I was surprised by that, as I found it crystal clear in its original form.

After a few days, seeing that it was still on hold (actually, it had been closed, but I didn't realise) and that nobody had replied to my comment suggesting to reconsider the "on hold" status, I decided to **propose some edits** to make it even clearer (remember, I am ***not*** the author of the question, but I do understand it and have the same question).

My **edit got approved, but the question is still closed**.

The "closed as unclear" (or "put on hold as unclear") info box seems to encourage to edit the question to make it clearer. It doesn't offer any option to submit it for review to those who closed it as unclear. There's no option to request to reopen it, either.
So I assumed that, **by editing it**, those who had closed it would automatically be notified of the edits and be asked to evaluate whether those edits make the question sufficiently clear to be reopened.

Isn't that so?

Actually I now see that the person who approved my edit *is* one of those who had closed the question.

So, is the question still not clear enough?

Personally, the only doubt I had about this question is whether it might be considered off-topic, because it's not strictly about programming or code, but about how to use a tool. But given this tool is strictly a **development** tool, I think the question is perfectly within the scope of Stack Overflow.

But I don't see how it can be said to be unclear.

I wonder whether:

- those who closed it made the mistake of considering that, because they have no idea what the answer is, the question is not clear enough; or
- they genuinely believed it to be unclear in its first formulation (and let's concede they were right), and they were biased by that initial impression when reviewing the edited version; or
- they forgot to examine whether the edit made the question clear enough to be reopened; they just reviewed the edit as such and approved it
- **none of the above. I'm just wrong**, and the question is **still unclear**, despite my edit.

Comment: A couple points because you have some wrong assumptions: There's a reopen queue where questions get sent the first time they're edited after being closed. The people who then review it aren't likely to be any of the same who closed it the first time. The original closers are in no way notified that the post gets edited. After the post is edited, reopening requires reopen votes cast from several users (I believe 5), so it can take a while even if it is ready to be reopened.

Comment: The question in question never went through the reopen review queue.

Comment: Ah here's why it didn't make it to the reopen queue: "Any question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue, as well as any post edited within five days of the question's closure." [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), it was closed on May 27th, and the edit was approved on June 2nd, so that's 6 days. If someone casts a reopen vote on it now, though, it'll go into the queue.

Comment: Your first guess is [pretty accurate](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=46332082#46332082).  SO users do have only one shot at making a good first impression, odds for success go rapidly downhill from there.  Do consider asking the question yourself.

Comment: FYI: Contrary to what you say in the question, neither of the people who approved your edit voted to close the question.

Comment: It has 4 re-open votes now, one more and it will be re-opened

Comment: @HansPassant That is why I will never ask a question on SO.  I don't see any point in engaging in an activity that has such low odds of success.  I think that's what makes me (and many others) believe the site is inherently unwelcoming.  Hopefully that changes sometime:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: @JerryJeremiah My experience with asking questions is quite different from yours then. On the rare occasion that I can't find the answer on SO already and I post a question I've usually gotten at least one answer. My bar for asking a question here is very high but that's not because the site is "unwelcoming", it's because more likely or not the answer is already here somewhere and I just need to find it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The odds for success go down after the first impression due to the volume of incoming questions. Even when looking at 'Active' questions a post still has to compete with new questions as well as questions that were just edited or answered. That's a different problem than folks being rude or the site not having the right tools.

Comment: Re _"I found it crystal clear in its original form"_, I am constantly surprised at questions that are put on hold as  _"unclear what you're asking"_ when those questions are crystal clear to me. I see this a lot with Java in particular, and I suspect that some folks here who would claim to know Java actually only have a rudimentary knowledge. So some clear (and interesting) questions may end up getting inappropriately closed as "unclear" by those with limited experience.

Comment: I found the reason in my code, the continuation of the topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472959/dom-overload-problems-in-google-chrome

Comment: @skomisa That's certainly one way of interpreting it (one particularly uncharitable to closers). Another is that what is clear to one person may not be clear to another, and we should strive to make questions clear to everyone.

Comment: @HereticMonkey _"we should strive to make questions clear to everyone"_: Sure, but sometimes valid, clear and interesting questions cannot and need not be "dumbed down" - you just need a certain level of understanding to know that the question is clear as it stands. In a similar vein, see [Hans Passant's comment to an answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385796/question-closed-because-unclear-edits-accepted-not-reopened/385808#comment701736_385808): _"...everybody today feels entitled to find the answer to any question, even though they know next to nothing about it"_.

Comment: @skomisa I guess my point was that 5 people voted to close a question as "unclear what you're asking". Perhaps that's enough of a signal that one might want to ensure the question is actually as clear as one hoped. I'm not sure how it relates to feeling entitled to an answer.

Comment: @skomisa The phenomenon you describe is precisely why we have an editing feature, and why we let experts (judged by reputation, albeit imperfectly) edit without any friction. If a question is “crystal clear” to you, but not others, there are very good odds you’re bringing background knowledge or context to the table that is not stated in the question. By editing the question to add in that information, and make the question *more* clear, you not only prevent it from being closed, but also make it more useful to others and more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO - very rarely will something get reopened once closed; whether your edit makes it more clear/proves it's not a duplicate or not.

Comment: ...and so the close/reopen battles start.

Answer (score 17):

After the original closure, the question has now been reopened (probably due to meta effect), but is already at two close votes *again*.

My impression why this is happening:

- From a question **asker** perspective, the question is abundantly clear: "I'm seeing this behavior and have no idea where it comes from. What's happening?". People with the same issue (such as the meta OP) will (evidently) find this question, can confirm that it is the same question they have and expect to find an answer.
- From a question **answerer** perspective, I can see why people would prefer/require an MCVE (i.e. a reproducer). Without that, there is little anyone can do to *find* an answer (as explained in the question comments), so even though the question is clear enough that a good answer *should exist*, it seems impossible to *find* or *give* the answer without further information (a reproducer).

In particular, given the allegations of a bug/regression in Chrome, it appears that there is no known answer (as of the time of asking) and actual debugging work might be needed. That's obviously not something that the asker can know before asking, but I can understand the reasoning behind the close votes.

Comment: This has been changing a lot at SO in the past five years.  I think it is a social phenomenon, everybody today feels entitled to find the answer to any question, even though they know next to nothing about it.  Thomas Nichols talks about it in his book "The Death of Expertise".  Not a positive development, SO by itself probably contributed to it a great deal.

Comment: "In particular, given the allegations of a bug/regression in Chrome, it appears that there is no known answer (as of the time of asking) and actual debugging work might be needed. That's obviously not something that the asker can know before asking, but I can understand the reasoning behind the close votes." Whether the asker can know that a Chrome bug is involved is irrelevant to creating an MCVE, as demonstrated by the fact they created one in another question. I agree with @HansPassant. The original is a essentially a request for one-on-one debugging help, which make for bad questions.

Comment: @ jpmc26: Covered by the old close reason "Too localised"?

Comment: @jpmc26 I understood Hans the other way around: Every _answerer_ feels entitled to give an answer and "retaliates" with close votes if they can't (even when they're not supposed to).

Comment: @HansPassant While you do have a valid point, it also seems like many new askers feel entitled to free debugging as soon as they hit an obstacle. Creating an MRE (as it is called nowadays) is often a very good way of showing others that you have made an effort on your own. For me, it is actually very common that the MRE:s I create results in not posting a question at all, since the process of creating the MRE solve the problem for me.

Comment: For some problems it's (almost) impossible to create an MRE, and sometimes it would not even make the question significantly better. For other problems, it's almost impossible to solve without. But then we also have questions that CAN be answered relatively easy without an MRE, but at the same time, an MRE would be very easy to create. In this case, I don't see the reason why you should not provide an MRE, even though it's not strictly necessary. I would not vote to close such a question, but I would downvote it for lack of research.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Unlikely for two reasons. 1. The kind of answerer you describe wouldn't being trying to **"find"** an answer. They would just want to already know it. Expertise is developed and improved by searching for answers in documentation, testing, discussions, etc. Having a lot of people who dig deep into looking for one would mean we'd have more experts, not fewer. 2. Close votes are not nearly as common as questions asked by people who have a poor grasp of their question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would say that we have a problem with edits that gets approved when they should not, so just the fact that an edit has been approved does not mean much.

Secondly, just because your edit made the question clearer, it does not mean it made it clear enough for reopening. The process is like this, whenever a closed question get edited or a reopen vote, it goes into the reopen queue and then people look at the question and see if it is fit for reopening. See [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/6699433) for details. This is completely separate from the process where your edit got approved. Please note that a question can have multiple applicable close reasons, and if just one of them is solved, then reopening to reclose it for the correct closing reason is not something that we do here. It's not considered important enough.

In general, don't edit closed questions unless you are pretty confident they will get good enough for reopening. It's a waste of both your and others time.

Answer (score -2):

I was fooled with this bizarreness of following up to a closed question by asking a new question. Can we close [Inexplicit 'task' in Chrome Perfomance DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56329780/14768) as a duplicate of [DOM overload problems in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472959/dom-overload-problems-in-google-chrome) that seems like it's closest to the OP's intent now that we have two questions.

Merge would be nice but it's really hard to merge those two question texts.

Comment: Merging questions copies the answers from one to the other.  That's pointless when neither question has any answers.

Comment: @Servy: I was sincerely hoping it would copy the question votes over too.

Comment: Given how things turned out, duplicate closure should proceed in the other direction. Also, if the question is really about how to debug the problem / understand the output in the screenshot (rather than about the specific phenomenon that turned up), the questions should be edited to reflect that.

Answer (score -15):

You can ask the question, but what's the point of omitting the MCVE?

Similar to [Is it inappropriate to ask what a compiler error message means?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326267/is-it-inappropriate-to-ask-what-a-compiler-error-message-means), in this case there might be multiple different reasons why the problem occur, and if there are, it would be a good idea to make sure that the answers actually applies to your code.

Unless you intentionally want to post a [canonical question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261900/how-to-make-canonical-questions-acceptably-specific).

---

But what if you know the answer, and you know that there's only one correct answer?

Perhaps you can repost your own Q&A. Sometimes people's perception of a question's clarity is affected by the existing answer ([related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223454/do-too-broad-questions-become-less-broad-after-an-acceptable-answer-is-given)), but you can add a MCVE to be sure.

Comment: not all questions need a mcve. 'debug my code' ones do, but fortunately there are others.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Isn't this a debug question? (what part of the code cause this [strange behavior])

Comment: @user202729: No. It's a  "Why does my debugger not work?" question. That's different from "why does my code not work?".

Comment: @BDL I don't understand what's the problem? The behavior is caused by the code, and it might be the case that the code just do nothing at that time (I am not familiar with the technology involved)

Comment: This one needed an MCVE.  I'd love to know how to get to a state where we get the tasks that the OP described.  The question lacked enough information on how to get to the state the OP described and is, to me, too broad.  Given the context of an MCVE, we might be able to get better insight or even spin up a debug build of Chromium and get to the heart of the problem.

Comment: @zero298 Eventually others managed to reproduce the underlying problem and give answers. But even without knowing how to reproduce the problem, "**How do I** use the debugger to figure out what's causing the problem?" is a valid category of question. Literally phrased that way it would be too broad, but OP narrowed the scope appropriately.